# Angular Js how to get checkbox value on edit and submit?

Tags: angularjs

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="mail.email" name="email"
       ng-true-value="'mail.email'" ng-false-value="'0'">
```

This is my code while im going to edit i need to fetch the value from database but if i click the checkbox it shows the following response

```
{
    regid: "NADr333434", 
    email: "mail.email", 
    altemail: "mail.altemail", 
    htmlcontent: "<b>kuhiuhioh oih oihih</b>"
}
```

I need the output as the follwing format how to get this

```
{
    regid: "NADr333434", 
    email: "test@gmail.com", 
    altemail: "alternate@test.com", 
    htmlcontent: "<b>kuhiuhioh oih oihih</b>"
}
```

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: _"I need the output as the follwing format"_ - As far as I can tell, the two examples has the exact same format, just different values

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D

Comment: For future reference, only add tags that are relevant to the issue. I've removed the non-relevant tags: php, codeigniter, css and jquery since this is a question about angular.